# How to use update query in many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables:

Users(id, username, sum_score, level)

user_badge(user_id, badge_id)

badges(badge-id, badge_name)

user_id and badge_id from user_badge are foreign keys for the ids in other two table.

I would like to update the user_badge table when the following condition is satisfied.

```
$selectscore= "SELECT sum_score from users WHERE id= '$id'";
$selectscorequery=mysqli_query($db,$selectscore);

while($set=mysqli_fetch_array($selectscorequery)){
if ($set['sum_score']>=0) {

$newbie="UPDATE user_badge a JOIN users u ON a.user_id = u.id JOIN badges b ON a.badge_id = b.badge_id  SET a.badge_id = b.badge_id WHERE user_id='".$set["id"]."'" AND b.badge_id='7';
  mysqli_query($db,$newbie)or die(mysqli_error($db));

 }
```

I tried insert ignore query at first but it was not working, it was just adding a new row every time. So i used the update query. I know there is something wrong with the query. Could someone help me out with this problem. I never used update on many to many relationship before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right you will give a user the badge_id=7 when his sum_score is greater then 0 ?

In this case I don't want to work with joins, because in my opinion you only have to update the table user_badge to set the relationship

```
    $selectscore= "SELECT sum_score from users";
$selectscorequery=mysqli_query($db,$selectscore);

while($set=mysqli_fetch_array($selectscorequery)){
  if ($set['sum_score']>=0) {

  // Query if badge already exists
  $selectbadge= "SELECT user_id from user_badge WHERE badge_id='7' AND user_id='".$set["id"]."'";
  $selectbadgequery=mysqli_query($db,$selectbadge);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($selectbadgequery)<1) {
    // INSERT THE BADGE      
    echo "insert Batch Newbie for User User: ".$set['id']."\n";
    $newbie="INSERT user_badge (user_id,badge_id) VALUES ('".$set["id"]."','7')";
  } else {
    // UPDATE THE BADGE  
    echo "update Batch Newbie for User User: ".$set['id']."\n";
    $newbie="UPDATE user_badge SET badge_id = '7' WHERE user_id='".$set["id"]."' AND badge_id='7'";
  }

    mysqli_query($db,$newbie)or die(mysqli_error($db));

  }
}
```

Comment: but the tables are connected. The user_badge(id, user_id and badge_id). so the user_id is referred from users table and badge_id is taken from badges table. With you query i dont think its connecting the tables. I tried you query and its working. Could you resolve it

Comment: excuse me ... Due to read your comment I am not sure: Does it Work or Not?

Comment: Do you get any sql Error Statement?

Comment: did you understand my question?

Comment: Now i found something similar to my problem in google, and i have updated the code. Can you check it

Comment: May explain it more briefly, so: where there changes in the user_badge table by running this code? Does an entry with the badge-id = 7 exist in the badges table?

Comment: i tried with your code, there was no entry in the table with badge id ='7'

Comment: I try to assume the following:
table Users is filled with at least 1 user
table badges is filled with at least 1 badge 
table user_badges is filled with at least one line per user_id with one individual badge_id

Is this right ... if not: explain the current situation

Comment: Ok, great ... give me one defined badge_id out of the table badges

Comment: badge_id: 7 badge_name: newbie.

Comment: ok please add a line, between the $newby-line before and the mysqli-command-line with echo $newbie; ... rund the script and try to post the echo

Comment: the script is not running, because there was no echo output

Comment: If there is no echo output we stuck in a problem before our UPDATE query ... please set a echo after $selectscore-line with echo $selectscore; and post the output.

Comment: Excuse Me, there were also miner faults in the code ... I updated the code ... please take this, run it and post the output

Comment: Now the output is updating the existing rows. but that is not what i want. I needed to update the row that has only badge_id =7. The user_id can have many badges, with the above code it just updates the existing row of user with the new badge_id=7

Comment: Now the script is changed also for inserting badges to users with a additional check if the user has the badge allready or not. Was this that what you are looking for?

Comment: Now its working like what i wanted . Thank you so much for your support

Comment: No Problem ... You are Welcome!